# Where to find twitter analytics data?

Tags: twitter

I cannot find twitter analytics data on ads.twitter.com On many articles is written that I just need to click the "Analytics" tab but I can't find it!
[image]

Comment: Twitter appears to have analytics only for advertising campaigns that you have created on twitter.  Have you done any advertising on twitter?     There are third party analytics available through an app that is geared to twitter users: http://www.twitonomy.com/

Comment: Don't forget to approve the answer if you like it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The Twitter Analytics site is [here](https://analytics.twitter.com/about).